# echo a variable inside a php string replace

Tags: php

I currently trying to do a str_replace in PHP which is new to me. Here is my current code.

```
$postAddress = str_replace("/current-url/", "/path/to/my-news/post/", $postAddress);

<li><a href="<?php echo $postAddress; ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></li>
```

However in the above URL where I have 'my-news' I want to change that so it outputs the URL stored in the admin. So rather than doing an if statement for each category I want to output it as a variable.

Here is what i've tried to do:

```
$postAddress = str_replace("/current-url/", "/path/to/"echo $cat->getTitle() "/post/", $postAddress);
```

I hope this is enough info. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: concatenation is with `.` operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think You have to do this:

```
$postAddress = str_replace("/current-url/", "/path/to/".$cat->getTitle()."/post/", $postAddress);
```

Comment: I won't don't worry, it's this damn 10 minute countdown! :) Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshDavies - 10 minutes have passed ;)

Answer (score 4):

have a look at [PHP String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
$postAddress = str_replace("/current-url/", "/path/to/" . $cat->getTitle() . "/post/", $postAddress);
```

Comment: I will accept the other answer as he was first. But seriously, thank you! +1 for extra info!

Comment: You do that - he was indeed first :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$postAddress = str_replace("/current-url/", "/path/to/" . $cat->getTitle() . "/post/", $postAddress);
```

Is that what you want? Use . for concatenation and don't echo the variable.